# how to change all value into new column if specific value is exist - bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I tried for couple of hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request

I have table like this

```
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|cust_id|date_   |order_rank|cust_segment|segment_new|
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |11-2021 | 1        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |11-2021 | 2        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |12-2021 | 3        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |10-2021 | 1        | SE         | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |11-2021 | 2        | ORG        | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |12-2021 | 3        | ORG        | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |10-2021 | 1        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |10-2021 | 2        | SE         | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |11-2021 | 3        | SE         | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

What I want to is if the first "order_rank" is ORG but in the rest of "cust_segment" in same "cust_id" are segment SE is exist then I want to change all "segment_new" in same "cust_id" into SE like table below

```
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|cust_id|date_   |order_rank|cust_segment|segment_new|
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |11-2021 | 1        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |11-2021 | 2        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|10     |12-2021 | 3        | ORG        | ORG       |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |10-2021 | 1        | SE         | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |11-2021 | 2        | ORG        | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|20     |12-2021 | 3        | ORG        | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |10-2021 | 1        | ORG        | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |10-2021 | 2        | SE         | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|30     |11-2021 | 3        | SE         | SE        |
+-------+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I do that? if someone know, pls tell me.. Thank You

Comment: expected result shown for cust_id = 20 does not follow the outlined logic! please revisit

Answer (score 0):

Your question text conflicts with the sample result, so I have suggested 2 queries with 1 that complies with the text, and a second that matches the expected result.

This complies with the question text `if the first "order_rank" is ORG but in the rest of "cust_segment" in same "cust_id" are segment SE is exist then I want to change all "segment_new" in same "cust_id" into SE`

```
update data1
set segment_new = (case when order_rank = 1
                              and cust_segment = 'ORG'
                              and exists (select 1 from data1 cs
                                          where data1.cust_id = cs.cust_id
                                          and cs.order_rank > 1
                                          and cs.cust_segment = 'SE')
                          then 'SE'
                          else cust_segment
                     end)
;
```

the result of this is:

```
  cust_id    date_    order_rank   cust_segment   segment_new  
 --------- --------- ------------ -------------- ------------- 
       10   11-2021            1   ORG            ORG          
       10   11-2021            2   ORG            ORG          
       10   12-2021            3   ORG            ORG          
       20   10-2021            1   SE             SE           
       20   11-2021            2   ORG            ORG          
       20   12-2021            3   ORG            ORG          
       30   10-2021            1   ORG            SE           
       30   10-2021            2   SE             SE           
       30   11-2021            3   SE             SE
```

to match the expected result table of the question:

```
update data1
set segment_new = (case when cust_id in(select cust_id from data1 where cust_segment = 'SE')
                        then 'SE'
                        else cust_segment
                   end)
;
```

This result is:

```
  cust_id    date_    order_rank   cust_segment   segment_new  
 --------- --------- ------------ -------------- ------------- 
       10   11-2021            1   ORG            ORG          
       10   11-2021            2   ORG            ORG          
       10   12-2021            3   ORG            ORG          
       20   10-2021            1   SE             SE           
       20   11-2021            2   ORG            SE           
       20   12-2021            3   ORG            SE           
       30   10-2021            1   ORG            SE           
       30   10-2021            2   SE             SE           
       30   11-2021            3   SE             SE
```

[sqlfiddle for both queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/756ff/5)